# Kendo upload control does not upload file using ajax POST

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-upload

I am using kendo upload control to post file to server

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("file")
    .Async(a => a.Save("DocumentUpload", "Home")
    .AutoUpload(true))
    .Multiple(false))

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DocumentUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
          var isAjax = HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
          // Why isAjax is false here ?? Is it not Ajax POST?
    }
```

I thought kendo makes ajax POST request. 
However this is not true, in asp.net `HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()` returns `false`.
When i check request headers i dont see `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` header as well.
Is this a bug in kendo upload?

Is there anyway to configure kendo upload control to make ajax POST?

Comment: I am in the same boat and wondering if you have come across any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it does use a `POST` by default.

I think your issue is that the `name` of your widget is `file` and your argument is `files` (plural).

Alternatively, you can set `.Files("files")` like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Deferred()
    .Name("upload")
    .Multiple(true)
    .Async(async => async.AutoUpload(true)
        .SaveUrl(Url.Action("SaveAttachment"))
        .SaveField("files")))
    .Events(evt => evt.Success("refreshAttachments")))
```

Comment: I am not saying its not using POST. It does use POST and it post the file to server as well. However the issue is it is not Ajax POST. Inside controller action method 'HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()' is false

Comment: @LP13 Sorry, your question wasn't quite clear on that.  I'm not exactly sure why it wouldn't set `IsAjaxRequest` to `true`